# cannot uninstall or reinstall visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, installation, uninstallation

I wanted to install vS 2015 but got an error so I then tried to uninstall visual studio 2013 first prior to installing VS 2015.

And now I see I cannot even reinstall (or uninstall) VS 2013.

When I try to uninstall VS 2013 I get this error

"an error occurred while trying to uninstall microsoft visual studio ultimate 2013. It may have already been uninstalled. Would you like to remove microsoft visual studio ultimate 2013 ultimate from the programs and features list".

I said no 'cos I want to uninstall it properly And then that dialog box cancels but it isn't uninstalled

[image]

I can go into visual studio. So it is installed.

I then tried to reinstall since that may fix the uninstaller.

Then I get this error

[image]

"setup failed. Install cannot continue because some required components failed.   Please correct the following problems and restart the setup..."

The end of the log file states

```
[4DC0:4408][2016-06-06T17:57:42]i000: MUX:  Free Disk Space before install:  SystemDrive C:\ 49307762688 bytes  AppDrive C:\ 49307762688 bytes
[5014:372C][2016-06-06T17:57:45]i360: Creating a system restore point.
[5014:372C][2016-06-06T17:57:55]i361: Created a system restore point.
[5014:372C][2016-06-06T17:57:55]i370: Session begin, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{dca572ee-b6f6-4560-9879-fec58cc0022c}, options: 0x7, disable resume: No
[5014:372C][2016-06-06T17:57:55]e000: Error 0x80070003: Failed to create cache directory: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{dca572ee-b6f6-4560-9879-fec58cc0022c}
[5014:372C][2016-06-06T17:57:55]e000: Error 0x80070003: Failed to create completed cache path for bundle.
[5014:372C][2016-06-06T17:57:55]e000: Error 0x80070003: Failed to cache bundle from path: C:\Users\harvey\AppData\Local\Temp\{dca572ee-b6f6-4560-9879-fec58cc0022c}\.be\vs_ultimate.exe
[5014:372C][2016-06-06T17:57:55]e000: Error 0x80070003: Failed to begin registration session.
[4DC0:4408][2016-06-06T17:57:55]e000: Error 0x80070003: Failed to begin registration session in per-machine process.
[4DC0:4408][2016-06-06T17:57:55]e000: Error 0x80070003: Failed to register bundle.
[4DC0:4408][2016-06-06T17:57:55]i000: MUX:  Apply Complete: Disk Space Used in bytes for Installation:  MaxAppDrive: 0  MaxSysDrive: 349683712  AppDrive: 0  SysDrive: 74588160
[4DC0:4408][2016-06-06T17:57:55]i000: MUX:  Free Disk Space after install:  SystemDrive C:\ 49233174528 bytes  AppDrive C:\ 49233174528 bytes
[4DC0:4408][2016-06-06T17:57:55]i000: MUX:  Set Result: Return Code=-2147024893 (0x80070003), Error Message=, Result Detail=, Vital=True, Package Action=Install, Package Id=Apply Failure
[4DC0:4408][2016-06-06T17:57:55]i000: MUX:  Go to Finished page.
[4DC0:4408][2016-06-06T17:57:55]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80070003, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
```

Comment: I don't remember what I did.. I recall clicking to remove that entry so, perhaps not uninstalling visual studio properly, but removing that entry.

Comment: I don't remember what I did.. I recall clicking to remove that entry so, perhaps not uninstalling visual studio properly,  I then tried installing VS 2015, maybe got an error(don't recall what), and I may have selected and uninstalled some .net entries in add/remove programs.

Comment: How about trying to click Yes to remove vs from progams and features list, and reinstall it?

Comment: @yuyangJian clicking "yes" where?  if you mean from the program's uninstall,.. if the program's uninstall was there then I probably tried it and then would've got the same error so not mentioned it, Most likely the uninstall in 'programs and features' is the same as the one in the start menu  anyway. (though I don't recall if there was one in the start menu).